# Create database in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

How can I create a database via a stored procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateDataBase 
    @strDBPath nvarchar(MAX),
    @strFileName nvarchar(50),
    @strLOGPath nvarchar(MAX),
    @strLOGFileName nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE DATABASE [APPLICATION]
    CONTAINMENT = NONE
    ON  PRIMARY 
    ( NAME = strFileName, FILENAME = strDBPath, SIZE = 5120KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
    LOG ON 
    ( NAME = strFileName, FILENAME = strLOGPath , SIZE = 2048KB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
END
GO
```

In SQL Server Management Studio everything seems alright. But in my Visual Studio database project the compiler complains about `strDBPath` and `strLOGPath`.

Error:

> Incorrect Syntax near strDBPath

Answer (score 0):

Because you try to use them as variables NOT USING THE PREFIX @ in your statement. I am pretty sure, if you would READ the error message (quite telling you do not include it in your question here, you know) it would hint you in this direction.

Comment: Well its saying incorrect syntax near strDBPath...

Comment: I need the @ Prefix when i define a variable, I CANT use the @ prefix, if i use the variable.

Comment: @GejekoPatrick - Petty distinction: "@" is not a prefix, like dereferencing a pointer in some languages, it is the initial character of a variable or parameter identifier as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx), (Except when it is the first of two "@" characters used in some T-SQL function names.) It doesn't come and go depending on where the variable or parameter is being used.